# Calculating a function from its auto-correlation

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, signal-processing

How do I calculate a function if I know its auto-correlation?

To be more specific, I have a function of one variable, let's call it $g(x)$, and I know it's the cross-correlation of a function $f(x)$ with itself. In formulas
$$
g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)f(x+t)dt
$$
I want $f(x)$, how do I get it?

If possible, I would like to have an analytic answer. Otherwise, I actually have $g(x)$ sampled in a finite number of points, so a numeric procedure to derive $f(x)$ would also do the job.

Thanks!

Comment: as lulu said you can't recover the function for its auto-correlation : you need more informations to find $arg \mathcal{F}[f]$

Comment: @user1952009  Thank you!  I managed to confuse myself utterly.  I'll delete my (unhelpful) comments.

Comment: Thanks @user1952009 and lulu.
So what happens if I calculate $\mathcal{F}(g)$, get its square root and inverse-Fourier transform the result? Do I get something related to $f$ in some way?